# Gradle Copy task: Why can "from" method be called with configuration closure that can call "into" method?

Tags: gradle, groovy

Consider the following example from gradle documentation (slightly simplified):

```
task initConfig(type: Copy) {
     from('src/main/config') {
         include '**/*.properties'
         include '**/*.xml'
         filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [version: '2.3.1'])
     }
 }
```

Here, the "from" method is declared in AbstractCopyTask class with the following signature:

```
public AbstractCopyTask from​(Object sourcePath, Closure c)
```

where c - closure for configuring the child CopySourceSpec. The CopySourceSpec is an interface which declares only "from" methods.

Question: Why is the closure in the example above allowed to call "include" and "filter" methods if it is by documentation configuration closure for child CopySourceSpec which only allows invocation of "from" methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `include` is [coming from](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.java#L338) the `AbstractCopyTask` parent

As an example, you can do this in groovy:

```
class FromSpec {
    String who
    
    FromSpec(String who) {
        this.who = who
    }
    
    def capitalize() {
        who = who.capitalize()
    }
}

class Testing {
    FromSpec spec
    
    def sayHello() {
        println "Hello $spec.who"
    }
    
    def from(String who, Closure c) {
        this.spec = new FromSpec(who)
        c.delegate = this.spec
        c.call()
    }
    
    def run(Closure c) {
        c.delegate = this
        c.call()
    }

}
```

By using the Closure delegate, we can then do this

```
new Testing().run {
    from('peshi') {
        capitalize() // A method in the FromSpec
        sayHello()   // A method in the owner Testing class
    }
}
```

And we get the output

```
Hello Peshi
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Yates!